# UTF-8 encoding breaks JSP embedded with other than English Characters

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding, servlet-filters

I am trying to append additional content to the `HttpServletResponse` using a `CharReponseWrapper` (which is in turn invoked by my filter).

In order to support multiple languages such as Chinese and Korean, I have to ensure that the resultant content (after appending) preserves the original charset and encoding. Therefore, I obtain the charset by invoking `super.getContentType()` and parse it to extract the charset.

For example,  `super.getContentType()` might return `text/html; charset=UTF-8` which I parse to extract `UTF-8`.

Subsequently, I supply the charset while creating `PrintWriter` object (which wraps the `OutputStreamWriter`). (note: `try/catch` omitted for clarity)

CharResponseWrapper.java :

```
public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
{
 ....
@Override
  public PrintWriter getWriter() 
  {

            String charEnc = getCharsetFromContentType(getContentType());
            if (charEnc != null) {
                pwriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(getOutputStream(), charEnc), false);
            } else {
                pwriter = new PrintWriter(getOutputStream());
            }
          }
      return pwriter;
  }
 ....
}
```

- I have a JSP with Korean text.
- In that JSP specified `contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` and `pageEncoding="UTF-8"`.

JSP's Source:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    out.println("한글자모 / 조선글");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to access the JSP with Korean characters I am getting few ��? garbled characters in browser.

But I am getting the garbled characters with response page like given below.

```
한글��?모 / 조선글
```

Edited: I tried out with adding empty string to front of the response, still I am facing issue.

Comment: If you add some characters in front (like spaces) are still the same Korean characters concerned? It could be some servlet filter that has a fixed block sized buffer and on its boundary cannot handle multibyte sequences correctly. If it are always the same chars then I do not understand: U+c790 = UTF-8 [ec 9e 90] does not seem that special. Like a compression filter that buffers the first 256 bytes to check whether compression is beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the content is not encoded , you can try for testing purpose to pre-compile your jsp with encoding type UTF8 and place the file in your app classes folder instead of jsp's.

Comment: I checked the java file in Tomcat work folder which is compiled version of jsp. The java file is UTF-8 encoded and inside the Korean characters are encoded properly.

Comment: Basically you need to use the same encoding in all the layers,from jsp page to request ,response objects .if you are using eclipse to save the file then check , left-click on the file->Properties->Check out ->Text file encoding. if it doesn't solve you can have a filter which will encode all the request like

Comment: public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
throws ServletException
{
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

Comment: I checked the encoding of JSP file. Its UTF-8.
Also I tried `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` also not working. Did you got simulated this issue in you environment? Do you have working code?. Please send and help me.

Comment: we used to pre-compile and place the class files under the classes folder in our project.instead of placing the jsp's directly.